# Line up CenterYAnchor of UIButton to UIPageControl Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have some code where I'm adding in a "close" `UIButton` to the `UIPageController.view`, and that works great.

WORKING CODE:

```
class func closeButton(_ pageController: UIPageViewController) -> UIButton {

    let button = UIButton()

    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())
    button.setTitle("Close", for: UIControlState())
    button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.left
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    pageController.view.addSubview(button)

    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36).isActive = true
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageController.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageController.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    return button
}
```

But then I tested my code on the iPhone X Simulator, and the `UIPageControl` is much higher from the bottom than the other iPhones. So now that close button I just added is in the bottom rounded corner and the `UIPageControl` is much higher.

So then I tried referencing the the `UIPageControl` with:

```
let pageControl: UIPageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
```

And then replace the `button.bottomAnchor.constraint...` with:

```
button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageControl.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

But this causes an error to be thrown. I tried printing the `UIPageControl.frame` and it is 0,0,0,0. So I'm assuming that has something to do with it.

Is there a way to make a constraint against the UIPageControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom view try to update your constraint in layoutSubviews() method, or in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method of your view controller:

```
func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageControl.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: I splitting the function into two parts. One that creates the button, and one that constrains it. The first part that creates it I am still calling in the `ViewDidLoad`, but the 2nd part that constrains I am calling in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. You're suggestion got me there. Most could probably just put it all in 'viewDidLayoutSubviews', but I have another part that decides if its `isHidden = true` and so the button needed to be created at 'ViewDidLoad' Thanks again!

Comment: Good choice ;) In viewDidLayoutSubviews you get your pageControl frame and that’s why you can update your constraints there, instead the part where you create your button it’s correct to call in viewDidLoad. You are welcome ;)